# Stripe offsite on Cognito forms

Tags: cognito-forms

Is it possible for Stripe Payments to be done like Paypal i.e. just with a button that takes you to Stripe? If I went to a site I didn't know I would much rather be taken off site to put in my details than input at that site.

Comment: Question title should not include tags. Reference: [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 1):

Stripe does not support a dedicated checkout page like PayPal.  There are pros and cons to each approach, but from our own experience an integrated checkout process is better for customers.

At the same time, if you are embedded your Cognito Form in your website, it is important to make sure you are using HTTPS/SSL, at least to ensure your customers feel confident about the security of their transaction.